# Set individual glyphtext for MKAnnotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I want to create `MKPointAnnotaion`'s with the `identifier`  number in the annotation overlay instead of the pin. So a `1` for the first annotation, a `2` for the second annotation, etc.

First, I added an `MKPointAnnotation` to the `mapView` based on a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

With the `mapView(_:viewFor:)` I want to style those Annotations. This works to a certain extent but brings us to my problem:

I created a class `CustomAnnotation` to add an `identifier` to my MKPointAnnotaion:

```
class CustomAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var identifier: Int!
}
```

And I set the `identifier` when registering `UILongPressGesture`:

```
let annotation = CustomAnnotation()
annotation.identifier = mapView.annotations.count
```

Then I use `mapView(_:viewFor:)` to change the appearance of my `MKPointAnnotaion`'s. But I do not know how to set `annotationView.glyphText` so that it uses the `identifier` defined before for every created annotation individually.

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is CustomAnnotation else { return nil }

        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
        annotationView.glyphTintColor = .white
        annotationView.glyphText = "44"
            
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.kodeco.com/7738344-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-009 your annotationView has a field annotation. you set that field in the code you've shown. Then you subclass your annotation and store in it whatever you want, including your index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @[Gerd Castan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4566480/gerd-castan) for your reference to the very extensive tutorial at
[kodeco](https://www.kodeco.com/7738344-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-009)

In the following I give a brief overview how I solved my problem - it might help someone in the future.

First of all I changed the type of my `CustomAnnotation` class from a `MKPointAnnotation`to an `MKAnnotation`. Now it is actually applicable to every Map Annotation use case.

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    @objc dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title:String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var identifier: Int?
    
    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D,
         title:String?, subtitle:String?, identifier:Int?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.identifier = identifier
   }
}
```

Then I created a class for the view representation of the `CustomAnnotation` called `CustomAnnotationView`. In this case the type is an `MKMarkerAnnotationView` but you can also use `MKAnnotationView` if you do not want the representation of the Annotations as markers.

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation?{
        willSet{
            
            guard let marker = newValue as? CustomAnnotation else { return }

            if let number = marker.identifier {
               let alphabeticRepresentation = UnicodeScalar(number+1+64)!
               glyphText = String(alphabeticRepresentation)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

One annotation to the code cell above:

1. If you do not want an alphabetic representation in your marker, then just delete the following line of code in the example above `let alphabeticRepresentation = UnicodeScalar(number+1+64)!`

In my `UILongPressureGesture` handler I set the `identifier`, so only the number of `CustomAnnotaion`'s are counted.

```
let identifier = mapView.annotations.filter{ $0 is CustomAnnotation }.count
```

In `viewDidload()` of the MapViewController I registered the `CustomAnnotationView`

```
mapView.register(CustomAnnotationView.self,
                  forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:
                  MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

That's it.